# How to activate MSDTC for SQL Server 2019 failover cluster

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019, distributed-availability-groups

I have configured a failover cluster and always on SQL Server 2019 high availability group on 2 nodes and operating system with Windows Server 2019.
I am trying to configure the MSDTC properties of the component service and it does not show me the option to activate it, I have seen that previous versions can enable cluster default coordinator.
Is MSDTC required for SQL Server 2019 failover cluster?

[image]